# namespaces is forbidden cannot list resource Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When I try to get ns , there is error

```
namespaces is forbidden: User "system:node:k8-node-1" cannot list resource
```

this is only when I try `kubectl get ns`

What is problem ? This is cluster install in BareMetal

Answer (score 0):

The `kubeconfig` which you are using does not have `clusterwide` priveledges to `list` all `namespace`

Here is a [task](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/home/container-orchestration/kubernetes/practice-tasks/task-gcp-027-intermediate-cluster-wide-kubeconfig) which you can use to create a `kubeconfig` which has the required priveledges